# Protractor - How to get first or last CHILD value

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I have some HTML which looks like this:

```
<div class="label label-primary ng-scope" ng-if="vehicle.manufacturerCode">
   <strong class="ng-binding">AUDI</strong>
   <small class="ng-binding">[00]</small>
   <span class="btn btn-flat" ng-click="axCarSearch.removeIdentification(1, $event)">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
   </span>
</div>
```

From this HTML i need to get values of first or last ng-binding.
I can imagine I can get to vehicle.manufacturerCode with something like:

```
element(by.css('[ng-if="vehicle.manufacturerCode"]'));
```

But not sure how i can go deeper and get string "AUDI" or string "[00]" to compare if they are equal.

It may looks like:

```
it('Compare results ', function() {
    var manufacturer = element(by.css('[ng-if="vehicle.manufacturerCode"]')).child[0];
    expect(manufacture.toEqual('AUDI');
});
```

Comment: Please show the initial non-rendered HTML code that contain bindings.

Comment: Hi @alecxe, I am not 100% sure what you mean. Can you please be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML you've provided suggests [`by.binding`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.binding) locators can be used, but you haven't provided the actual bindings - you can see them in the non-rendered HTML source code, e.g. should be smth like:

```
<strong class="ng-binding">{{ vehicle.manufacturer }}</strong>
```

In this case, you could've located the desired elements this way:

```
var div = element(by.css('[ng-if="vehicle.manufacturerCode"]'));

var name = div.element(by.binding("vehicle.manufacturer"));
var code = div.element(by.binding("vehicle.manufacturerCode"));

expect(name.getText()).toEqual("AUDI");
expect(code.getText()).toEqual("[00]");
```

---

From what you've provided, you can chain the `element` calls and rely on the tag names:

```
var div = element(by.css('[ng-if="vehicle.manufacturerCode"]'));

var strong = div.element(by.tagName("strong"));
var small = div.element(by.tagName("small"));

expect(strong.getText()).toEqual("AUDI");
expect(small.getText()).toEqual("[00]");
```

Note that, in general, relying on `ng-if` and tag names is not quite reliable.

Comment: if I get to values like '{{ vehicle.manufacturer }}', how can I use it in protractor if protractor see just result on site

Comment: @Andurit sure, give me a second.

Comment: thanks @alecxe, but are you sure, protractor can get to sourcecode before it is parsed by browser?

Comment: @Andurit sure, this is one of the angular-specific features protractor is providing.

Comment: I am going to try it, give me few minnutes:)

Comment: Incredible, WORKING! This is going to help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.label-primary').children().each(function () {
    //Use value here using $this
});
```

Use each loop to iterate all the children of the div.